# Move an ascii object based on spaces per second

Tags: c++, flush, frame-rate, ascii-art, usleep

I am trying to move a picture based on its vertical and horizontal speed. I understand that if, say, the word "Picture" were to be moving across the terminal screen at a rate of .25 spaces per second, I would write something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h> //for usleep()

int main()
{
        int pos = 0;

        screen_clear(); //clears the terminal screen
        for (pos = 0; pos < 30; pos++) {
                screen_home();
                for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                        cout << " ";
                cout << "Picture";
                screen_home(); //moves the cursor to the top of the screen
                cout.flush();
                usleep(250000); 
                /* I'm not sure if this is the right integer, but the usleep
                 * function takes microseconds as the input. */
        }
        return 0;
```

My question is, how do I implement a vertical shift and/or a negative speed (moves to the left rather than right)?

Comment: For a _vertical shift_ you need to print `pos` number of `'\n'` characters.

Comment: Where in my loops would I put the \n and how would I implement the speed of that vertical shift? (Vertical and horizontal speeds are not the same)

Comment: "moving across the terminal screen at a rate of .25 frames per second" doesn't even make sense... Unless, by "frames" you really mean "character positions"...

Comment: You do that after the 1st `screen_home()` call, use another `posY` maybe. To slow down the speed just do that only every nth time in the outer loop.

Comment: twalberg, yes character positions is basically what I mean in this situation